# Private folder to app not appear in Gallery

Tags: android, local-storage, android-10.0

As of Android 10, we have only one way to store the files in private folder only. We can access external storage but have to take user consent bla bla.... So I am storing images in android>data>package name>files>images folder. So after storing I used `MediaScannerConnection` `MediaScannerConnectionClient` `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` and many more. But images stored in this folder is not visible to gallery app.

Is there any way or workaround for this to make it work ?

Comment: `MediaStore` is now back to indexing only media. If your content is of a recognize media type, you could always store it using `MediaStore` itself, rather than in one of the `Context`-supplied directories. [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ConferenceVideos) allows the user to download some of my conference videos. I use `MediaStore` to store those videos, with separate code for Android 10+ and older devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare Right, but the problem is that such app specific media messed up with existing media already stored in device. If we want to separate with our own folder or directory then I think there is no way. Like externalStorage>myapp>images,PDF etc

Comment: @CommonsWare One more thing I forgot to mention that it does not allow to write text file, PDF file etc... in MediaStore location... Only image, video and audio is allowed. So what about this ?

Comment: "If we want to separate with our own folder or directory then I think there is no way" -- if your content is media, you can create an app-specific location within the media directory. [The sample project that I linked to previously](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ConferenceVideos) demonstrates this. "So what about this ?" -- use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`), and allow the user to choose where you store your content.